# Hibernate Error. A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance. After second session.flush

Tags: hibernate

I know that there is already a ton of questions referring to this error, but non of the solutions seems to apply.

I want to `create or update` parent entities "p" and `always delete old and create new` children entities "c".

On a Service, under an Async Controller with:

```
@Async("SomeExecutor")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

I am doing the following:

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

for (int i = 0; i < dtoListOfParents.size(); i++) {

    ParentEntity p = null;
    if(peKeyMap.contains(paKey)){    //just a map with the already existing ParentEntities that I fetch beforehand.
        p = peKeyMap.get(paKey);
    } else {
        p = new ParentEntity();
    }

    p.setSomeProperty(v1);
    p.setSomeOtherProperty(v2);

    if(p.getId()==null){
        p = (ParentEntity) session.merge(p);
    } else {
        p.getC.clear();
    }
    session.flush();    //to get parent id for on create or delete the children on edit.
    p.setC(dtoListOfCs, p);

    if (i % 50 == 0) {
        session.flush();  // Here is where I am getting the error.
        session.clear();
    }
}
```

Hibernate is "complaining" about the following:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" 
was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: ...model.ParentEntity.children
```

The Children entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "children")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class Children implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private ChildrenPK pk;

private ParentEntity parentEntity;
private SecondaryEntity secondaryEntity;


@EmbeddedId
public ChildrenPK getPk() {
    return pk;
}

public void setPk(ChildrenPK pk) {
    this.pk = pk;
}

public Children() {
}

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="parent_entity_id", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=false)
@MapsId("parentEntityId")
public ParentEntity getParentEntity() {
    return this.parentEntity;
}
```

The association on the ParentEntity side:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentEntity", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Children> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code is a little... peculiar, but is this line:

```
p.setC(dtoListOfCs, p);
```

overwriting `Parent.children` with a fresh collection?

Hibernate doesn't like it when you override a collection property of a managed entity with a fresh collection when the mapping is annotated with `@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)`. You need to use the original list instead, adding/removing children, and clearing it, if necessary.

(Note that the `Parent` entity returned from `session.merge()` will already have an empty collection created by Hibernate, even if it was `null` before the merge. You're supposed to use that one)

Comment: What do you mean overriding? At that point I have already done a get of children entity and clear of the collection and a flush of the session. What else needs to be done before I am able to set the new collection? (for your note) I know it's going to be empty and it is since it's set to lazy, that's why I am doing a get and not just creating a method in the entity to say this.children.empty().

Comment: That's the whole point, you're not supposed to set a new collection on `Parent.children` when `Parent` is a managed entity, **ever**. You're supposed to use the one returned by Hibernate. Just add the children to the original collection (`parent.getChildren().addAll(...)`). It's critical that you retain the same collection **instance**, because Hibernate relies on that to implement the orphan removal functionality. The contents of the collection, though, you can change however you like

Comment: That is correct. Thank you! Also I had to use `Hibernate.Initialize(p.getChildren())` right before that I had to make a `session.refresh(p)` of the parent entity, otherwise Hibernate throws `collection is not associated with any session`